# In Scala, how to perform an exact comparison match when iterating on each Map key?

Tags: dataframe, scala, dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark

Ultimately, my goal is to iterate over a Map that contains several thousand records, and compare each matching key, with a column name from a Dataframe that has a hundreds of columns.

I have a Dataframe that has a subset of objects:

```
 val petDF = Seq(
   (1, “dog”),
   (2, “cat”),
   (3, "horse")
 ).toDF(“Rank”, “Animal”, …several hundred columns)
```

And a map or dictionary with key/value pairs that has a superset of objects.

```
val lookupMap = Map (
   “Rank” -> “Rating”,
   “Animal” -> “Pet”,
   “Human” -> “Person”,
   “Neighbor” -> “Friend”
   …several thousand records…
)
```

I need to iterate over the map/dictionary and, for each match with the Dataframe column, I need to reassign the column name in the Dataframe depending whenever there is a match on the key.

For instance, when there is a match on the Map’s key `Animal` then the Dataframe column name needs to be renamed to `Pet`.  And then when there is a match with the Dataframe’s column name on the Map’s key `Rank` then the Dataframe column needs to be renamed to `Rating`.  But, there should be no impact to the Dataframe when there is no matching Column name in the Map; like for `Human` or `Neighbor`.

My problem is, that I am trying to figure out how to iterate over each value in the Map and perform the comparison with each value of the Dataframe’s columns.

I tried using the construct for Map `.contains()` but the `if` is True every time the loop evaluates

```
for ((k, v) <- lookupMap)
{ if( lookupMap.contains(“[column name]”) { [rename column]}
}
```

This doesn’t work because the `if` evaluates to `true` every time with `.contains()` each time.

Is there a better way to iterate over the Map and perform the comparison with a matching column?  There will be hundreds of matches.

TL;DR -  The particular problem that I’m stuck on is iterating over each key in the map and comparing the exact value with a matching column in the Dataframe.

Comment: I haven't used **Spark** in a lot of years, but a quick check in the current **Scaladoc**: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html shows a method called `withColumnsRenamed` which basically already does all this for you, just pass the `Map` to that method and call it a day.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [@Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%c3%ada-su%c3%a1rez) in the comments you can utilize `withColumnRenamed()` to rename the columns using your `lookupMap` as follows:

```scala
val currentColumns = petDF.columns
val renamedPetDF = currentColumns.foldLeft(petDF) { (df, colName) =>
  lookupMap.get(colName) match {
    case Some(newColName) => df.withColumnRenamed(colName, newColName)
    case None => df
  }
}
```

Now, why does your if-condition always evaluates to true? You need to understand how `contains()` works. Here's an example:

```scala
for ((k, v) <- lookupMap) {
  if (lookupMap.contains("Animal")) {
    println("Match found for 'Animal'")
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Match found for 'Animal'
Match found for 'Animal'
Match found for 'Animal'
Match found for 'Animal'
```

Here, when the loop iterates over each key-value pair in `lookupMap`, the condition `lookupMap.contains("Animal")` will always be evaluated to true for every key in the map. This is because `contains("Animal")` checks if the key "Animal" exists in the entire map, not just for the specific key being iterated over at that moment.

Also, nothing will be printed (always false) in case you replace "Animal" with something which is not present as a key in the `lookupMap` because the *map does not **contain** the specified column name as a key*.

Check the [scala documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/maps.html) on different ways to do lookups on `Maps`.

Comment: There is no need to `foldLeft` there is an overload of the method that takes a `Map[String, String]` and apply all the mappings at once.